# Execute python file from another python file by passing argument as variable

Tags: python, pdfminer

In the below code, I am trying to take the path name (inclusive of file name) and converting them to another path name with text file.

Now I would like to pass both variable as argument for another py which will take it as argument

```
import os

thisdir=[os.path.join(r,file) for r,d,f in 
os.walk("C:\\Users\\vnitin\\OneDrive - NetApp Inc\\IDP\\Files\\") for file 
in f]
for i in range(len(thisdir)):
    text_path = thisdir[i].replace('pdf', 'txt')
    print(text_path)
    os.system('py pdf2txt.py -o text_path thisdir[i]')
```

But individual command for pdf2txt.py works very well.

```
py .\pdf2txt.py -o 'C:\Users\vnitin\OneDrive - NetApp Inc\IDP\Files\11.txt'  
'C:\Users\vnitin\OneDrive - NetApp Inc\IDP\Files\11.pdf'
```

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look to the `subprocess` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Comment: `os.system('py pdf2txt.py -o text_path thisdir[i]')` this executes as a string, so your `i` is not what you expect it to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `thisdir[i]` is not converted to its value during execution, so the error `No such file or directory`

Replace `os.system('py pdf2txt.py -o text_path thisdir[i]')`
with

`os.system("python ./pdf2txt.py -o {0} {1}".format(text_path,thisdir[i]))`

Comment: No it doesn't 
I am getting IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'thisdir[i]'

Comment: Now this.

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\vnitin\\OneDrive'

Not sure, why permission denied, because it works very well with the full path as argument.

Comment: Unsure of the permission denied error, can you check the file permissions?

Comment: Hi. it worked. I gave some better path and it went fine. Thanks a lot for quick help :)

Answer (score 0):

Two Solutions:
1)You can directly import and call the main method with params

```
data = pdf2txt.main(['pdf2txt.py',filename])
```

or

2) Form a string and pass it as a command

```
    string ="py .\pdf2txt.py -o" +" C:\Users\vnitin\OneDrive - NetApp Inc\IDP\Files\11.txt"+" C:\Users\vnitin\OneDrive - NetApp Inc\IDP\Files\11.pdf"
```

Comment: about the first point, after **import pdf2txt** and running the first option, it is giving error **ImportError: cannot import name 'maxint**

Answer (score 0):

Use [SubProcess module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("python ./pdf2txt.py -o {0} {1}".format(text_path,thisdir[i])", shell=True)
```

Now, stdin, stdout, and stderr can also be redirected.